# Upgrading Spring Boot Dependencies from 2.0.4.RELEASE to 2.2.13.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependencies, upgrade

I'm on a project where we're trying to upgrade dependencies to address security vulnerabilities, but I'm completely new to Spring Boot.

Previously, the spring dependencies were on versions 2.0.4.RELEASE, but the app doesn't work after upgrading to 2.2.13.RELEASE. The app can still compile using Maven after changing the dependencies.

Is there anything in particular that I should be taking note of when upgrading between these two versions? Have checked that all dependencies in the project that were previously on 2.0.4 were upgraded to 2.2.13.

Comment: Check https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#upgrading-from-spring-boot-20 and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes#upgrading-from-spring-boot-21 If you can provide more details about the error, we might be able to be more precise

Comment: What kind of details would be helpful?

The app compiles locally, but now we're trying to run it through a Jenkins pipeline where it fails.

For the app itself, there's an error regarding CORS Policy and XMLHttpRequest, but this seems to be a general error that we get whenever the sign in function of our app doesn't work properly.

Not really looking for a specific answer btw (though that'd be helpful), maybe just looking more of for guidelines of how to handle the dependency upgrading process

Comment: Then the 2 links above should give you all the checks to go through

Answer (score 0):

The errors should be printed to std out / console log when you run your application. As guessing, circular dependency can cause service to not start. With the errors you get, things can be clearer.